# Avoid postback on TreeView SelectedNodeChanged (inside jquery dialog)

Tags: asp.net

What I am attempting to achieve is basically this:

1. user clicks on save as button
2. dialog "pop-up" shows that has report categories and name entry
3. user enters a name, or selects category which loads old reports
4. backend will get the values from dialog and use those to update reports in database

My issue is that when I fire the MyTreeView.SelectedNodeChanged event, I am redirected to the aspx page that I'm showing in my dialog pop-up. Is there anything I can do to prevent this, or contain the postback? I included my code, but I'm guessing this will be something I will have to account for in aspx?

Here's some code:

ReportSave.aspx -- in dialog window

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ReportSave.aspx.vb" Inherits="ReportSave" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Save Report As</title>
    <link href="ReportSaveStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formReportSave" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <asp:Label class="report-list-title" ID="lblReportList" runat="server" Text="Report List"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TreeView class="report-list-items" ID="trvReportList" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>

            <asp:Label class="category-tree-title" ID="lblReportCategory" runat="server" Text="Report Category"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TreeView class="category-tree-items" ID="trvCategoryView" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>

            <asp:Label class="save-input-title" ID="lblReportName" runat="server" Text="Report Name"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox class="save-input-textbox" ID="tbReportName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Button class="save-button1" ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" />
            <asp:Button class="save-button2" ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend code - ReportSave.aspx.vb

```
Private Sub trvCategoryView_SelectedNodeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles trvCategoryView.SelectedNodeChanged
    Try
        'Dim li As ListItem
        'li = cblCategoryView.SelectedItem
        Dim node As TreeNode
        node = trvCategoryView.SelectedNode
        ' handle all categories
        If node.Value.ToString.ToUpper = "NEW CATEGORY" Then
            Dim strNC As String = InputBox("Enter Name for New Category", "Create Category")
            If strNC = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If strNC.ToUpper = "NEW CATEGORY" Then
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myalert", "window.alert('You can't have a Category Called New Category. Sorry!');", True)
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select recordno from Reports where ReportType = '" & strNC & "'", conn)
            Dim strresult As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar
            If IsNothing(strresult) Then
                Dim temp As TreeNode = New TreeNode(strNC, strNC, "Images/file.png")
                ' Dim temp As ListItem = New ListItem(strNC, strNC)
                'lvCategoryView.Items.Add(temp)
                'SetSelectedListItem(lvCategoryView.Items(lvCategoryView.Items.Count - 1))
                'cblCategoryView.Items.Add(temp)
                trvCategoryView.Nodes.Add(temp)
                FillReports()
                lblReportList.Text = "Report List for Group " & trvCategoryView.SelectedValue.ToString
                ' cblCategoryView.SelectedValue

                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myalert", "window.alert('That Report Group Already Exists');", True)
            End If
            cmd.Dispose()
            cmd = Nothing
            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()
            conn = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'SetSelectedListItem(li)
            FillReports()
            lblReportList.Text = "Report List for Group " & trvCategoryView.SelectedValue.ToString
            'cblCategoryView.SelectedValue.ToString
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help in advance! I am new to Web Development as well as ASP.NET. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making the assumption that you are loading this form into an iframe, and would guess that the problem lies in the implementation of the MyTreeView.SelectedNodeChanged event or the parent page itself.

Thinking outside the box, Web Forms may have alternate solutions to accomplish your objectives.  The implementation of an iframe would be my least favorite.  Depending on your specific requirements, these options may work better for you.

1. Nested Masterpages
2. Re-usable User Control (ascx) in overlay (popup) DIV element
3. Update Panel in overlay (popup) DIV element
4. AJAX post to Handler (ashx)

Comment: user8790030 -  response to 3. I've seen people using an Update Panel to 'contain' the postback on the page. I had trouble using CSS with my ASP.NET components nested in the Update Panel though... is that a known issue?

Comment: CSS shouldn't give you trouble in an Update Panel.  I load the styling with the main page (or Master Page).  Look at the generated html to be sure you are using the correct selectors -- Web Forms adds containing elements for most controls except Literal.  Also, ASP controls may have generated unique IDs depending on your settings.  JavaScript event bindings must be done after elements are loaded in the page, so if you are using dynamic styling that would require awareness.

Comment: I used the 3rd method and it worked perfectly! Thank you